# Classes of Banach algebras (that aren't operator algebras) whose bidual comes from a "universal representation"

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Are there any classes of (Arens regular) Banach algebras that are not operator algebras whose bidual comes from a “universal representation”, as in the case of C*-algebras?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sort of depends on what you mean by "universal representation".  For $C^*$-algebras, I think the statement is usually the following: Given a $C^*$-algebra $A$ and a representation $\pi:A\rightarrow B(H)$, let $M(\pi) = \pi(A)''$ denote the von Neumann algebra generated by $\pi(A)$.  There is a unique surjective normal $*$-homomorphism $\tilde\pi:A^{**}\rightarrow M(\pi)$.  (Here I followed Takesaki's book.)

For Banach algebras, we need to decide what the analogue of "von Neumann algebra" is, and perhaps what "normal" should mean.

---

One solution is to focus on *dual Banach algebras*, that is, Banach algebras $A$ for which there is some predual $A_*$ making the multiplication separately weak$^*$-continuous.  Then "normal" means weak$^*$-continuous.  Such algebras have long been studied, with Runde undertaking a lot of study.  In my paper [Dual Banach algebras: representations and injectivity](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2289356) [arXiv:math/0604372](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0604372) I study representations of dual Banach algebras on *reflexive* Banach spaces (using ideas of Young).  Typically I fail to make a clean statement, but we have:

- If $E$ is a reflexive Banach space then $B(E)$ is a dual Banach algebra with predual $E\widehat\otimes E^*$, and so any weak$^*$-closed subalgebra of $B(E)$ is a dual Banach algebra.
- By Corollary 3.8 every dual Banach algebra is isometrically weak$^*$-weak$^*$-continuously isomorphic to a weak$^*$-closed subalgebra of $B(E)$ for some reflexive $E$.
- There is a closed submodule $\newcommand{\wap}{\operatorname{wap}}\wap(A^*)$ of $A^*$ which is maximal so that the quotient map $A^{**}\rightarrow\wap(A^*)^*$ induces a single product on $\wap(A^*)^*$ for either Arens product.  In particular, $A$ is Arens regular if and only if $\wap(A^*)=A^*$.
- $\wap(A^*)^*$ is hence a dual Banach algebra, and it satisfies the universal property we hope for: see Proposition 2.9 (due to Runde).  If $B$ is any dual Banach algebra, a homomorphism $A\rightarrow B$ admits a unique extension a weak$^*$-continuous homomorphism $\wap(A^*)^*\rightarrow B$.

So let $A$ be Arens regular, and consider a representation $\pi:A\rightarrow B(E)$ for some reflexive $E$.  Then we obtain a unique extension $\tilde\pi:\wap(A^*)^* = A^{**} \rightarrow \overline{\pi(A)}^{w^*}$.  If $\pi$ induces a *bounded below* map $A/\ker\pi\rightarrow B(E)$ then $\tilde\pi$ will be surjective (from Hahn-Banach).  In general, I don't see that $\tilde\pi$ will be surjective.

To better answer the **original question**: "yes".  If we take $\pi:A\rightarrow B(E)$ to be a "maximal" representation on a reflexive $E$ (e.g. the sum of all cyclic representations, "cyclic" chosen to obtain a set not a proper class) then $\pi$ is an isometry (follows from Theorem 3.6, also from Young's work) and $\tilde\pi:A^{**}\rightarrow B(E)$ is an isometry, so $A^{**}$ is the weak$^*$-closure of $\pi(A)$.

(In the last few years, Thiel and Gardella have studied similar things, but I don't have an exact reference.)

---

A second approach is to take a more permissive approach to what a "representation" is: just any bounded homomorphism $\pi:A\rightarrow B(E)$ for any Banach space $E$.  This is the same notation as a (bounded) left $A$-module, and I will sometimes use the module language.  Any $A$ has an isometric representation: let $E=A\oplus_1\mathbb C$ be the unitisation, and $\pi$ the left-regular representation, so $a\cdot (b,\alpha) = (ab+\alpha a, 0)$ for $a,b\in A, \alpha\in\mathbb C$.  But $B(E)$ carries no (natural) weak$^*$-topology.

Instead, we could use $E=A^{**}\oplus_1\mathbb C$ with the predual $A^*\oplus_\infty\mathbb C$, and the left-regular representation.  Then the predual becomes a right module for the action $(a^*,\beta)\cdot a = (a^*\cdot a, \langle a^*,a \rangle)$ with the usual action of $A$ on $A^*$.  Then $B(E)$ does not become a dual Banach algebra, but it does become a one-sided dual Banach algebra (see work of Spain, and Thiel and Gardella, for more on this notion).  Furthermore, there is a standard way to extend the action of $A$ on $E$ to an action of $A^{**}$ which turns $E$ into a left $(A^{**},\Box)$ module, where $\Box$ is the first Arens product.  A check shows that this agrees with the weak$^*$-extension of the action of $A$, and the image in $B(E)$ is $A^{**}$.  Thus again $A^{**}$ arises as the weak$^*$-closure of a "universal" representation of $A$.

The difference here is that this only works with the first Arens product (a similar construction uses the second Arens product) but we don't need Arens regularity.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. How do you get that $\tilde{\pi} : A^{**} \to B(E)$ is an isometry? The usual proof in the C*-algebra case uses the Kaplansky Density Theorem, and the simplest alternative proof I can think of uses the polar decomposition of normal functionals.

Comment: Does Lemma 3.4 in your Dual Banach Algebras paper suffice as a replacement for polar decomposition?

Comment: Yes, exactly that!  Lemma 3.4 gives you the norm control you need.